# Multiple arrays in formula

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I need to count the number of a certain symbol in a range

I have tried using an array formula but it returns `#N/A`

The below code will work:

```
{=SUM(If(MID(B297:B298,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},1)=$B$299,1,0))}
```

where I'm counting the number of times the symbol in `$B$299` appears in the range `B297:B298`

This code doesn't work

```
{=SUM(If(MID(B297:B298,ROW(1:8),1)=$B$299,1,0))}
```

I need to search each cell in range over 250+ characters. Is there a way to use `ROW(1:255)` for example, or do I need to type in `{1,2,3,4,5...254,255 etc.)`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simplier way.

Case sensitive approach ("a" and "A" are different):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B297:B298)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B297:B298,$B$299,"")))
```

Case insensitive approach ("a" and "A" are the same):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B297:B298)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B297:B298),LOWER($B$299),"")))
```

Comment: Another great option, many thanks, in the end I've gone with this: {=SUM(IF(MID(Search_text,COLUMN(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(Search_text))),1)=Search_character,1,0))}'{=SUM(IF(MID(Search_text,COLUMN(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(Search_text))),1)=Search_character,1,0))}

Comment: note, that using `INDIRECT`, `COLUMN` or `Row` makes your worksheet __very__ slow, because this formulas are _volatile_ and recalculates each time _any_ cell on worksheet changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with simoco's approach but to address the specific problem you had, because B297:B298 is a **vertical** range the 1 to 255 part needs to be a **horizontal** range, so you need to `TRANSPOSE`, e.g.

`=SUM(IF(MID(B297:B298,TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:255)),1)=$B$299,1,0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or you could use `COLUMN` function instead of `ROW`, e.g.

`=SUM(IF(MID(B297:B298,COLUMN(1:1),1)=$B$299,1,0))`

This **isn't** case-sensitive so if B299 contains "M" it counts both "m" and "M"